# How to restrict torrent download over WIFI?

Tags: wireless-networking, bittorrent

I have a DLink WIFI router with "admin" rights. I want to restrict torrent and other download over network. Please help. I am new to networking.

Answer (score 2):

Two options jump to mind.

1. [Block common bittorrent ports](http://www.ehow.com/how_7214748_block-bittorrent-ports.html).

   Most routers allow you to block certain ports, so you could block 6881 - 6999.  That would cut out a significant amount.
2. Block common trackers.

   Again, most routers provide the opportunity to block connections to certain websites.  If you do a bit of research, you could find the common trackers.  I will use one that is no longer around for an example: block: `*.demonoid.*`, for example.

If your reason is legality, I would go with option 2 because not all bittorrent is illegal (it's a very effective way to transmit large amounts of data - example: Linux Distros).

If your reason is just bandwidth - then the port method would be more effective.  Or a combination of the two.  Of course, there are always ways around it if someone is determined enough.